# Raspberry Pi 4 does not respond ssh

Tags: boot, pi-4, ssh

My setup is a RaspberryPi4 with SSD (Kingston 120GB) as boot drive. It has also a regular HDD connected to it. Both hard drives are connected [to a USB dock](https://www.tooq.com/product.php?id=1523) via 3.0 USB. The dock has also a power supply so no energy problems should arise. Connected via ethernet to router. SSH enabled. I have setup an apache server with Nextcloud (which it hasn't been started to be used because of the problems stated below) and also is setup as a client for a Wireguard VPN.

The problem is that when I turn on the RPi4 I can ssh to it without any issues, but if I leave it powered ON overnight, the next day I try to connect to it, the ssh console (or whatever I try to use) just freezes or behaves abnormally.

One day I could log in but I could not run any "complicated" commands (just `cd` and `ls` were working) and trying to run commands like `sudo nano` just left my ssh window frozen, no output. And today for example it just does not connect. I can ping the RPi4, but ssh refuses to let me in. It just freezes after inputting the password, no output from the RPi4.

I don't know what might be happening, this is the first time something like this happens to me, but I think it could be related to the USB dock with the hard drives in it? How can I know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities, from a heavy load that is running to a faulty SD card.

First thing is to examine the logs. Does the syslog give any hints? Errors/warnings? If so: this is probably the first thing you need to correct.

Next would be the filesystems. Any at 100%? What about swap?

Can you run a `vmstat 10 > /tmp/vmstat`  until it crashes? that would give some information about whether the system is extremely loaded.  If the `vmstat` shows extreme load, you might try

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do
    top -bn1 >>/tmp/top
    sleep 10
done
```

(or put the output on some external drive if your sdcard is relatively full). That will give you an idea of the process that causes the load.

Comment: I'm going to leave the script running tonight to see if tomorrow i still have the same issues. Just a quick note, in my setup I point out that I do not have an sd card to boot, but a SSD instead, don't know if that may be the issue or not. I even also increased the swap size to 2GB so the Raspberry had more space for programs to run

Comment: So I have been running it for 2 days and so far no issues... also no weird things on the logs so I don't know... if it does not start failing i think i will mark your answer as the one that "solved" the issue... what a weird thing...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is a heavy memory workload, so there is a lot of swapping. I had similiar issues when I executed too many programs at once.

Try disabling swapfile, then the heavy memory application should be killed more likely and ssh should be still available.

Try this day via `sudo swapoff -a` This disables swap until the next reboot.

Comment: The thing is that I do not really have installed that many programs. I mean, there's only wireguard and apache server. I'm going to use the script that @Ljm_Dullaart left on their answer and leave it overnight so i can see which processes were taking the most resources from my Pi. I might have to consider more lightweight options for the pi tho...

Comment: I don't really think it might be a swap issue as I have an SSD and I have allocated lots of swap space onto the SSD. Also been checking with `top` command the most consuming processes and no one had more than 0.5% of the RAM in use... so I don't know